# How to recover all data query?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I need recover all data from a query (null and non-null)

This is the HQL I'm using:

```
select a.fecAltaEjProf as fecAltaEjProf, a.fecBajaEjProf as fecBajaEjProf, b.idCategoria as idCategoria
from ejerprof a, categoria b
where a.idcategoria=b.idcategoria;
```

This returns:

```
fecaltaprof    fecbajaprof    categoria
-----------    -----------    ---------
NULL           26-08-1989     whay
22-08-1898     22-01-1500     NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by recover & what is expected from this query is unclear.

Comment: Looks like translation fail from a Roman based language (Spanish?). Try asking someone who's more proficient in English to review your question. If I'd do an educated guess, you actually meant to say "retrieve" or "obtain".

Comment: Looks like you **need left outer join** or **full join** read chapter 14.3 here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: I want to see all data and if they are empty they also appear.

Comment: From what you posted as query output, already NULL fields are fetched, can you update post with required output.